# Acces denied when trying to create trigger - mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, triggers, privileges, sql-grant, workbench

I m using mysql workbench and i am trying to create a trigger but i receive this error : ERROR 1419: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable).

I tried to do this **`SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;`** but again, i have no privileges.

Apparently, the problem is that the only user of this database (root) doesn't have so many privileges. 
The root was created like this :

```
**create user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
grant all on licenta.* to 'root'@'localhost';**
```

Also, I have no right to create a new user.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: normally on every default MySQL installation the root user would have all ALL privileges.. Are you renting the MySQL access by a webhosting company?

Comment: i m using localhost, at my home